# How to make the gmapping algorithm use only laser scan topics to build maps？

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I learned from reading the relevant links of gmapping that gmapping uses odom and laser scan to build maps. Is there any way to let gmapping only accept laserscan data to build maps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409569/how-to-make-the-gmapping-algorithm-use-only-laser-scan-topics-to-build-maps%EF%BC%9F/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping node subscribes to the odometry data of your robot (topic name) and also the laser scan. The only package I know about that uses only laser scan data to build map is hector mapping ...for that to work you have to get a transform from map to base_link to laser_frame  of your robot .

---

Originally posted by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) with karma: 96 on 2022-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on 2022-11-21**:
I have used Hector to get the map I want. I want to ask again what method can I use to build a map with the topic of odom?